# Multiple File Upload using PHP JavaScript in to dynamic folder structure

Tags: php, javascript

Please anyone help me how to solve the following requirement using javascript and php.

when user upload(multiple file) any document we need to save that on the server, folder naming convention will be based on Year of date of birth (YYYY) and inside that (YYYY) folder will be a subfolder based on (MM) and then (DD) and then will be user Last name and inside that will be user first name. User will select type of the document i.e. assume "X, Y and Z"(Assume dropdown).

Create the file name on the server(Replace all the spaces with '~'  and '/' with '!=')(File name will be yyyymmdd_lastname_firstname_documenttype.filetype),  if a file already exists with same name use number(1,2,3,….) at the end. 
e..g if a User Andy Walkar's  dob is July 2 1979 document xyz.pdf is uploaded. His file name on the server will be  "1979_07_02_walkar_andy_X~.pdf"  and file will be uploaded on in the folder "Docs\YYYY\MM\DD\LastName\FirstName"

I am able to do single file upload into a server folder which is already exists on the server. But I am unable to implement mutiple file upload in to a dynamic folder structure. Thanks in advance.

Sorry for my english.

Comment: That a lot of...instructions.

Answer (score 2):

We are here to provide solutions to problems, not write all your code for you. That being said, a great solution to your problem is a jQuery plugin called [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/).

> Uploadify is a jQuery plugin that integrates a fully-customizable multiple file upload utility on your website. It uses a mixture of Javascript, ActionScript, and any server-side language to dynamically create an instance over any DOM element on a page.

Answer (score 0):

I tried Uploadify, but UI customization was difficult.

So My choice is [fancyupload](http://digitarald.de/project/fancyupload/)
another good file uploader lib.

You can manipulate uploaded file name with your php code. 
and can customize your UI easily.

> FancyUpload is a file-input replacement which features an unobtrusive,
>   multiple-file selection menu and queued upload with an animated
>   progress bar. It is easy to setup, is server independent, completely
>   styleable via CSS and XHTML and uses MooTools to work in all